# Visual studio adding capital A to function name in error message

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I've tried making a minimal testcase to reproduce it, but haven't been able to.

Adding a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFUdo.png) to show the error

this is the call to the SetClass function

`m_luaState["MyClass"].SetClass<MyClass, I32>("AddTo", &MyClass::Add);`

This is the MyClass:

```
class MyClass 
{
public:
    MyClass(I32 i) : m_i(i), m_j(2*i)
    {

    }

    I32 m_j;

    void Add(I32 iv)
    {
        std::cout << iv + m_i + m_j;
    }

private:
    I32 m_i;
};
```

Comment: Not Visual Studio. It is real name of the system function. The suffix "A" is for "ansi". Press F12 on RegisterClass and you will see.

Comment: F12 takes me to the function on the left in my screenshot.. the State::RegisterClass.. also I am calling it on an instance of that function (m_state)

Comment: Please don't post pictures of your error message – post the text.

Comment: Windows is a Unicode OS. Using ASCII strings and functions is not the best idea. There's a reason that *all* samples, examples, SDK code and projects used macros like _T. This can lead to a lot of pain and customer complains *unless* your only users live in the US and never,ever, try to change their locale, eg, to Spanish. They should also never, ever try to load Unicode files (UTF8 or UTF16). If you have to pick an encoding, pick the unambiguous, native one

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The problem have nothing to do with the OP wanting to use ANSI system calls (the OP isn't even calling the Windows API `RegisterClass`), but because of the incredible stupid way Microsoft kept backwards compatibility when introducing Unicode into its API.

Comment: @molbdnilo: I wanted to show the line numbers as I was expecting this to be missunderstood as it seemed like some very wierd behaviour. But yeah.. could have explained it too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `RegisterClass(...)` method name is being replaced by a Windows `#define RegisterClass`.  Since you are compiling as ANSI, you are picking up the ANSI alias for `RegisterClass` which is `RegisterClassA` (it would be `RegisterClassW` if you were compiling Unicode).

You could either rename your `RegisterClass(...)` method if that's a viable option, exclude the conflicting Windows header (probably not an option), or conditionally `#undef RegisterClass` at the top of your header which declares your `RegisterClass(...)` method, something like:

```
#ifdef RegisterClass
#undef RegisterClass
#endif
```

Some additional reference about the conflicting symbol: [RegisterClass function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633586(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Setting this as answere as it was the first one :)

Answer (score 2):

This problem is actually quite interesting, and is nothing you have done wrong. It's because the [`RegisterClass`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633586(v=vs.85).aspx) Windows function and how Windows handle Unicode when programming.

Windows have two variants for almost all its function, if you see the table at the bottom of the [linked MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633586(v=vs.85).aspx) you will see them mentioned as `RegisterClassW` and `RegisterClassA`. The `W` function is used for Unicode builds, where all strings and characters are of type `wchar_t`. The `A` variant is the "ANSI" variant, using normal `char` characters.

The problem here is that Windows uses macros to decide which of the funcitons to use, basically it does this

```
#ifdef UNICODE
# define RegisterClass RegisterClassW
#else
# define RegisterClass RegisterClassA
#endif
```

This is problematic because the preprocessor will replace your call to the `RegisterClass` member function with the `RegisterClassA` symbol, leading to your error.

The simple solution is to `#undef` the `RegisterClass` macro directly after including `<windows.h>` (or in some other suitable place). Another is to rename `RegisterClass` to something which doesn't clash with the Windows function.

Comment: Actually it *is* the OP's problem. Windows is a Unicode OS but the OP uses non-Unicode classes like `string` instead of `u16string` or `wchar_t` or `char16_t`. In the past macros were used to allow the same code to work both for ASCII and Unicode. Nowadays - why use ASCII ? Instead of using `#undef` the OP should use the native format or use macros

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos As I commented to your other comment, the OP isn't calling the Windows API function `RegisterClass`, but a member function of a totally unrelated class that happens to have the same name.

Comment: That's probably the second level of hell. As for how backwards compatibility was implemented, it's better than the alternative - keep the same code and require end users to change their codepage to UTF8 if they want Unicode. This was meant to help with the transition to Unicode after all

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Phil beat you to it so putting his as the answere :)

Comment: @TLoe You can still upvote the answer if you found it useful... :)

Comment: If only my reputation was better :( I'm still too dodgy to count.. edit: oh.. this comment gave me enough reputation :)